# PHP - How to parse data from site with JavaScript dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing, dom

I am trying parse data from this site: www.sberbank.ua/branches/, and I am using simple HTML DOM Parser.

I tried this:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.sberbank.ua/branches/');
foreach($html->find("div.bitem") as $e) {
    echo $e->innertext."<br>";
}
```

This is the data that I need parse:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBDqk.png)

The problem is that the data is generated by javascript and when I tried get the DIV this was empty.

Please someone can help me to solve this?

Comment: Screen scraping is notoriously perilous. Have you tried hitting the URL in a browser without JavaScript turned on? Does the site in question have a non-JavaScript fallback?

Comment: @AndFisher yep I have tried it and the site doesn't works without javascript. There is not any GET request.

Comment: Then you cannot scrape the sites javascript generated information as `file_get_html()` does not run the javascript

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your answer, what I could do ?

Comment: There is Nothing you can do

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using Firebug extension for Firefox, with this I found the URL that the JS function uses to get the data. Finally I parsed the data from the new URL.